# Cloudformation Multi-Step Stack Deployment

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

We've built our entire platform using Cloudformation stacks and have dozens of services that follow the same deployment pattern:

Each service is broken out into two stacks. The first stack provisions an ECR repo for the app image and CodeBuild project to build the image. The second stack provisions the services using the `$latest` image from the previously provisioned ECR repo.

Before the ECR repo can have an image, the first stack needs to be deployed, and the CodeBuild project must be ran. Only once this is done can the second stack be deployed (otherwise the service cannot be provisioned because there is no starter image to use).

Having it broken out into these parts also gives us the ability to provision the same service with different configurations. Say I have an image processing service that creates image thumbnails. I want to configure that service differently if it is meant to handle real-time requests from users vs if it is a service that handles batch jobs. So my ImageProcessingService may be split into a UserImageProcessingService and BatchImageProcessingService but both services will use the shared ImageProcessingServiceRepo from ECR.

As a result, redeploying the same service to- say- another region cannot be easily automated without custom tools.

My question is:

How are you meant to automate deployment of Cloudformation stacks when multiple steps, especially steps involving tasks like submitting a CodeBuild job, are needed?

Is there a better way to structure my Cloudformation stacks to achieve my goal or is it not possible to do what I need to do without something like Teraform?

Comment: Are you using proper CI/CD tool, such as CodePipeline?

Comment: @Marcin I am using CodePipeline for deploying ECR images built by CodeBuild